# travelling salesman understanding constraints

Tags: linear-programming

I am trying to program TSP problem in R. From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) page section "Integer linear programming formulation", I was able to understand all the constraints except the last one.

Need help to understand the last constraint...what are the variable U/artificial varaibles? are they slack variables for earlier constraints?

Comment: For more info about that formulation, and the meaning of that constraint and variables, you may want to look for the MTZ (Miller-Tucker-Zemlin) formulation of the TSP. As already pointed out in @Boris Novikov's answer, those variables are used to avoid sub-tours in the solution. http://docs.mosek.com/6.0/capi/node015.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This constraint is introduced to avoid disconnected routes of the salesman. Indeed, if a route consists of more than one cycle, then summing the last constraints along the cycle with the length $k<n$, we obtain $nk\le n(k-1),$ which is impossible.

**Addendum:** Let we begin to solve a TSP by a method of the integer programming. On the first step we choose anywise the unknowns $x_{ij}=0,1$ and $u_i$. Thanking to the last constraints we necessarily get a connected route. The same thing happens on the second step etc. So we will only deal with connected routes.

Comment: I knew purpose of that constraint but what i dont know is what are the variable U/artificial variables that are mentioned on Wikipedia? are they slack variables for earlier constraints?

Comment: No, they are not  slack variables, i.e. they don't transform some inequalities into equalities. They take part only in  the last constraints.

Comment: i am still not clear :( They are not part of the Minimization objective. They dont appear in other constraints then how do they affect the solution? what is the meaning of 'artificial variables'?

Comment: by 'they' i mean U variable

Comment: @Cameron Buie: Thank you very much.

Comment: @user2543622: I added the answer.